# Why does Codeception / Selenium give "UnknownServerException"?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I've recently had some trouble getting automatic testing working on a new machine. I'm using Codeception and Selenium, and everything worked fine on my old Windows 8 machine (I'm now on Ubuntu). My coworker has also run the tests without problems on his Macbook. This is a Laravel project.

When I try to run the tests (with `./vendor/bin/codecept run acceptance`), a Firefox window opens, but does not resize to the specified window size, and never shows any content. After a minute or two, this is the terminal output:

```
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.0.9
Powered by PHPUnit 4.4.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

  [UnknownServerException]                       
  Process timed out after waiting for 45000 ms.

run [-c|--config="..."] [--report] [--html[="..."]] [--xml[="..."]] [--tap[="..."]] [--json[="..."]] [--colors] [--no-colors] [--silent] [--steps] [-d|--debug] [--coverage[="..."]] [--coverage-html[="..."]] [--coverage-xml[="..."]] [--coverage-text[="..."]] [--no-exit] [-g|--group="..."] [-s|--skip="..."] [-sg|--skip-group="..."] [--env="..."] [-f|--fail-fast] [suite] [test]
```

If I close the window before the error is displayed, then *another* Firefox window opens, but it resizes correctly and begins running the tests. Huh? I can't even computer...

Why does this happen?

**Edit:** Originally, when I closed the first window, I was getting another error, but upgrading to the latest Selenium (2.45.0) fixed that problem.

Comment: What is the code you are using to launch firefox?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using Codeception with the WebDriver module. Does that help?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Didn't realize the framework did that part for you. You'll need to wait for a codeception expert then, sorry.

Comment: Seems there aren't really any Codeception experts here. Did you try [filing a GitHub issue with the project?](https://github.com/codeception/codeception/issues) Or ever get a solution?

Comment: @c32hedge: No to both questions. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to either the computer or the project, as both are owned by a prior employer.

Comment: IIRC, I didn't have this issue when I moved to another computer running Debian Jessie.